# Update Preview is not working with XPM and DXA

Tags: 2013, experience-manager, odata, session-preview, dxa-1.2

We setup Experience manager using the [following guide](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-3C70F892-69F4-4FEE-922D-39F1AFEBD539&addHistory=true&query=experience%2520manager&scope=&tid=5a372a5a-65da-4b21-9fe2-0f79a4a9cdab&filename=GUID-3C70F892-69F4-4FEE-922D-39F1AFEBD539.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-3C70F892-69F4-4FEE-922D-39F1AFEBD539&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dexperience%2520manager&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1467138903837&currentQuery=experience%2520manager&currentScope=) with Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1 and DXA 1.2 (.NET) in the CD side. Most of it is working fine.

Inline editing is working fine for pages and components. When editing a single page (with global content as well), XPM works fine without any issues and content is refreshed when “Reloading the page” after successful publish.

We are hitting one issue with the update preview / refreshing the content for other publications (when global content was edited). The session preview ODATA service is accessible from both the CM and CD machines.

**Preview not up to date warning**

> The preview for this page is not up to date Your changes to this page
>   make an update of the page preview necessary

Upon clicking the "Update the Page Preview" or "Update Preview"; the CME is throwing the below error:

> Unable to update the changes using OData Service. The remote server
>   returned an error: (404) Not Found.

Developer console shows the below error.

[image]

CM Event logs show the following error.

> Unable to update the changes using OData Service. The remote server
>   returned an error: (404) Not Found.   Component:
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PreviewService Errorcode: 1003 User:
>   NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE  StackTrace Information Details:    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    at
>   System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveResult.BatchRequest(Boolean
>   replaceOnUpdate)    at
>   System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions
>   options)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PreviewService.ServiceImplementation.Preview(IEnumerable`1
>   publishedItemsInfo, TcmUri publishingTargetId)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PreviewService.ServiceImplementation.Preview(IEnumerable`1
>   publishedItemsInfo, TcmUri publishingTargetId)    at
>   SyncInvokePreview(Object , Object[] , Object[] )    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
>   isOperationContextSet)

I could not find much information in the logs to help assist further.

I referred [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411315/tridion-ui-bad-request) (very different error from above) and [HERE](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/13888/unable-to-update-the-changes-using-odata-service-with-dxa-xpm) (close but 406) but could not resolve.

```
Publication Target configuration:

Content Delivery Endpoint URL   : https://mysession-preview-service/odata.svc/
OData Access Token URL  : <Blank>
User Name               : <Blank>
Password                : <Blank>
Website URLs            : https://my-root-domain.com/
```

I am looking to enable inline editing for all children under my root parent domain like https://my-root-domain.com/context1, https://my-root-domain.com/context2 etc.

**Update 1:**

I am able to browse "https://mysession-preview-service/odata.svc" without any issues but "https://mysession-preview-service/odata.svc/" (with a trailing slash) is returning a 404 in the browser as well. Is this expected behavior?

> The resource cannot be found.    Description: HTTP 404. The resource
>   you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been
>   removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please
>   review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /odata.svc/

**Cd Core Logs:**

> 2017-01-09 15:03:10,084 ERROR WritableODataClaimProcessor - Resource
>   path is not valid!

Comment: How did you configure XPM settings on your Publication Target?

Comment: I have updated the publication target settings to the question Rick.

Comment: What do you get if you enter `https://mysession-preview-service/odata.svc/` in a browser?

Comment: I have updated the question Rick. Is that expected? Any specific configuration that I should be looking at?

Comment: Try removing the trailing slash from the CD Endpoint URL in the Pub Target config.

Comment: The same error persists Rick (without the trailing slash as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bindings in my web.xml was what was causing the issue with the ODATA service (a combination of how SSL termination happens in our load balancer and ODATA server). Thanks to Brandon (from SDL support) for pointing that out.

Finally, we had disable the DD4T cache and disable session preview for optimum acceptable behavior.

Thanks to Albert's blog on troubleshooting [SDL tridion XPM with session preview](https://albertromkes.com/2013/01/24/troubleshooting-the-sdl-tridion-experience-manager-with-session-preview/). Helped me confirm some of my above settings as well.